# In R, how to extract multiple variables from a column and create new variable

Tags: r

I have a dataset that contains multiple variables within one column [image: View of the data set]. I am trying to figure out how to extract the variables (6 unique questions) from column 'question' with their associated value in percentage of respondents. When I pivot wider, it doesn't return the results I need (image attached [image: output of pivot_wider])

My ideal output is a mean percentage of respondents, grouped by country and sex for each question.

i.e. an output that has
Country: Afghanistan, year, mean percentage of respondents per question.

dff2 <- df2 %>%
pivot_wider(names_from = 'Question', values_from = 'Percentage of respondents')

thank-you!

Comment: aaah.. the famous .NORM format at work  https://xkcd.com/2116/

Comment: Hi Halyleyaw, please read this after which it would be great if you could edit your post so that we can help you better: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to dcast your data.

from `reshape2` package, use `dcast()` function.

Here how to use it:

`dcast(data, Country + Sex ~ Question, value.var = 'Percentage of respondents')`

Use the names of without strings quotes `""`

[image]

Comment: Thank-you! Appreciate it.